# AWS Lambda: module initialization error: Error when running Camaro/Serverless

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've created a lambda function handler in NodeJS with Serverless. When I use the command: serverless offline start, I don't get any error. However when I want to deploy the app with the command serverless deploy, it deploys fine. When I want go to the endpoint, I'm getting an internal server error, this happens only when I require camaro in my application. I need the camaro library to create a template from XML.

I tried using node 6.10 and remove camaro, and install it with node 6.10. This doesn't make a difference.

This is the error I can view in Cloud watch:

> module initialization error: Error at Error (native) at
>   Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18) at Module.load
>   (module.js:487:32) at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12) at
>   Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3) at Module.require
>   (module.js:497:17) at require (internal/module.js:20:19) at
>   Object. (/var/task/node_modules/camaro/index.js:4:16) at
>   Module._compile (module.js:570:32) at Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (module.js:579:10)

**This is my index.js**

```
const serverless = require('serverless-http');

///
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();



// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
//serverless
module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

**This is my serverless.yml**

```
# serverless.yml
service: lambda-dashboardcb

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  stage: dev
  region: eu-west-1

functions:
  app:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
plugins:
  -  serverless-offline
```

**This is my package.json**

```
package.json
{
  "name": "lambda-dashboardcb",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "camaro": "^2.2.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "^4.15.5",
    "google-oauth-jwt": "^0.2.0",
    "googleapis": "^23.0.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-beta11",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.4.5",
    "serverless-http": "^1.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.13.3",
    "serverless-offline": "^3.16.0"
  }
}
```

**Router**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var metadata = require('../public/javascripts/metadata-onix.js');
var path = require("path");

var app = express();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public', 'index.html'));
});

router.param('isbn', function (req,res,next){
    next();
});

router.get('/metadata:isbn', function(req,res,next){
    /**
        - Get ISBN From URL
        - Get Metadata from ISBN, return as JSON
    **/
    var isbn = req.params.isbn;

    var info = metadata.getMetadataOnix(isbn).then(function(info) {
        res.json({ cover : info });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Module which uses Camaro**

```
const axios = require('axios');
const transform = require('camaro');

exports.getMetadataOnix = function (id) {
    /**
        - Create template
        - Get request to content CB API.
        - Transform data with template.
        - Return data.
    **/
    const template = {
       template stuff...
    }

    return axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'APIURL'+id,
        transformResponse: [function (data) {
            "use strict";
            data = transform(data, template);
            return data;
        }],
        // No .catch here
    }).then(function(resp){
        console.log('Cover from book:'+JSON.stringify(resp.data));
        return resp.data;
    });
}
```

Comment: Once you deploy to Lambda, use `serverless invoke -f <function-name> -l` to output a more useful error. In your case `serverless invoke -f app -l`. I had a similar issue with node-canvas, the binary was expecting packages in a specific directory, `/var/task/lib`, and I had them in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

camaro is a native module. you will need to install correct [prebuilt binary for AWS Lambda](https://github.com/tuananh/camaro#using-camaro-on-aws-lambda).

Even though you switch to Node 6.10 locally but the binary installed on your machine is built for your platform only, which maybe different with the platform on AWS Lambda.

> In order to use camaro on AWS Lambda, you should download a copy of prebuilt camaro from Releases and put to this folder path node_modules/camaro/lib/binding/camaro.node.
>
> As of currently, AWS Lambda only supports node 6 on Linux so you're looking for camaro-v2.1.0-node-v48-linux-x64.tar.gz.

Lambda already supports Node 8 now so choose the prebuilt binary accordingly.